# Have table inside div ignore max-width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div style="max-width: 100px; overflow: scroll">
  <table>...</table>
</div>
```

I want to limit the size of the `div`, but have the table stretch as far as it wants (i.e. ignoring the `max-width` attribute of the parent `div`. How do you do this? Currently the browser resizes the table in attempt to follow the `max-width`...

Comment: are you trying to set min-width or max-width of div?, If you are trying to set the max-width, why do you want to  ignore the max-width attribute of the parent div?

Comment: I only want to show a portion of the `table` and be able to scroll in the `div` to see the rest of the table. However, I don't want to `table` to adjust its size according to the `div`'s width.

Answer (score 0):

Set the position of the table to absolute, then it will not be constrained by the parent div

```
<div style="max-width: 100px; overflow: scroll">
  <table style="position:absolute;">...</table>
</div>
```

Comment: dangit i hit the downvote by accident then i try taking away with the upvote and theres no way to go back to ZERO lol

Comment: @Deryck: If you accidentally vote one way or the other, you can click that arrow again to undo it, as explained in the tooltip. Unfortunately, after a certain period of time (5 minutes if I recall), your vote is locked in until the post is edited.

Comment: Well once i hit the down arrow I figured hitting up would revert to zero but instead it increased all the way to +one.  And it kept doing that each direction.  I thought it was stack's way of saying, "choose wisely..."

Answer (score 0):

In CSS file:

```
div {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

You can't use the `position: absolute;` for the `table` element because it doesn't ignore the `div`...the `div` ignores IT.  If you don't have something filling up the div underneath the table it will not show at all.

PS - I said to put in the CSS file on purpose.  I see he has it in his HTML but you should rarely put CSS styles in HTML files.  Using a .css centralizes and standardizes across the site and all that has to be set are classes and ids.

Comment: in html <div style="overflow:visible; max-width:100px;">

Comment: Hmm... that sort works, but now the entire table is visible? How do you make it such that only `100px` of the table is visible?

Comment: are you looking for the table to be 100px just like the div?  Because you can just set your css to `table { max-width: 100px; width: auto; height: 100%; }` to make a 1:1 ratio for scaling.  If that doesn't help re-explain your goal for me.